# cassandra comments table data modeling

Tags: cassandra, datastax, cassandra-3.0

I wanted to perform query , select * from comments_by_post where post_id = 'postid';
I have designed comments table as follows-

```
CREATE TABLE comments_by_post (
    post_id text,
    posted_timestamp timestamp,
    actor_id text,
    comment_id text,
    actor_info frozen<actor>,
    actor_type text,
    comment text,
    PRIMARY KEY (post_id, posted_timestamp, actor_id, comment_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (posted_timestamp DESC, actor_id ASC, comment_id ASC)
```

Everything goes well, but the problem is when actor updates his/her information how can i update the actor_info then, because to update the information i need to provide post_id, posted_timestamp, and actor_id which is not feasible to update information one row at a time. what could be the optimum table.

Answer (score 1):

A frozen value serializes multiple components into a single value. Non-frozen types allow updates to individual fields. Cassandra treats the value of a frozen type as a blob. The entire value must be overwritten.

So when info about an actor is updated you should update the entire value for that actor in your comments table.

Later edit: Since the actor_info will not update very frequently you can do an select on actor_id in order to get the complete primary key and then do an update. Before doing that, a secondary index on actor_id has to be created

Comment: the problem is to update actor_info, i will have to provide posted_timestamp also, alongside actor_id.

Comment: Can you provide the definition for the actor also?